# How to switch between branches without bringing along file changes?

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to understand how I'm supposed to work on multiple different features in my project using git branching.  The problem I'm running into now is, I created a branch

`git checkout -b my-first-feature`

At this point I've changed a controller file in my application.  But, I've realized that I need to make a change in another stop of the project that is unrelated to `my-first-feature`, so I create another branch.

`git checkout -b hotfix-issue-#1105 master`

At this point I expected the controller file that was edited under `my-first-feature` to revert back to the contents of what was in the master branch, but it wasn't.  Did I forget a step? Or am I just doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to discard the changes in progress on your first branch, stash those changes before you switch branches:

```
git stash save "Stashing changes for later"
```

Then later you can switch back to that branch and retrieve your (stashed) changes:

```
git stash pop
```

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing